# tf.keras model to coreml model, BatchNormalization not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, coreml, coremltools

I'm working on an image recognition project which uses InceptionV3 from keras (tensorflow version). I've trained an output layer and I'm now trying to export it to a coreMl format in order to use it on ios devices.

Yet, I got the error :

> **ValueError: Keras layer '<class 'keras.layers.normalization_v2.BatchNormalization'>' not supported.**

when I ran :

```
model.save('IncepNet_SN_class.h5')

output_labels = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']

model_2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('IncepNet_SN_class.h5')

your_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('IncepNet_SN_class.h5', input_names=['image'], output_names=['output'], 
                                                   class_labels=output_labels)

your_model.save('IncepNet_SN_class.mlmodel')
```

Does anyone knows how to deal with it ?

Thanks a lot, Lucas.

Comment: You cannot convert a TF 2.x model with the Core ML tools Keras converter. You need to use `coremltools.convert(...)`

Comment: Sir, you're a real life hero. It worked perfectly, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

From comments

> You cannot convert a `TF 2.x model` with the Core ML tools Keras
> converter. You need to use `coremltools.convert(...)` (paraphrased from Matthijs Hollemans)